# C++ SFML object won't draw

Tags: c++, sfml

In the following code I try to draw a circle object in a composite object but it won't draw. And I don't know why. 
This code will never reach the circle draw method.

If I call the draw() method of circle in main.cpp directly it will draw..

drawable.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class drawable{
  public:
   drawable(sf::Vector2f position);
   virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow & window){};
   sf::Vector2f position;
};

class circle : public drawable{
  public:
   circle(sf::Vector2f position);
   void draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) override;
};

class composite : public drawable{
  public:
   composite(sf::Vector2f position, drawable part);
   void draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) override;
  private:
   int count = 0;
   drawable part;
};
```

drawable.cpp

```
#include "drawable.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

drawable::drawable(sf::Vector2f position) : position{ position } {
}

circle::circle(sf::Vector2f position) : drawable{ position } {
}

composite::composite(sf::Vector2f position, drawable part) : drawable(position), part{ part }{
}

void circle::draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) {
  sf::CircleShape circle;
  circle.setPosition(position);
  circle.setRadius(30);
  window.draw(circle);
}

void composite::draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) {
  this->part.position.x = this->position.x + part.position.x;
  this->part.position.y = this->position.y + part.position.y;
  this->part.draw(window);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "drawable.h"

int main()
{
  sf::RenderWindow window = sf::RenderWindow{ sf::VideoMode{ 640, 480 }, "SFML window" };

  circle circle{ sf::Vector2f{ 100, 200 } };
  composite composite(sf::Vector2f{ 200, 200 }, circle);

  window.clear();   
  composite.draw(window);
  window.display();

  while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)){
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
            window.close();
        }
    }
    sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(20));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Composite` takes `drawable` by value. This means that inside `composite`, you only get `drawable` objects; all information about the concrete type is lost. If you want to support polymorphic objects, you need to use pointers or references.